# Reshape pandas dataframe from wide to long

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to reshape the dataframe below:

```
        left_id                     right_id                    winner
482393  513d7a69fdc9f03587006808    513ceda3fdc9f035870023db    left
653153  513d5fc2fdc9f03587003c2d    5185d41afdc9f03fd500137c    right
1006476 5140c948fdc9f049260024b4    50f5e76afdc9f065f0007152    right
```

to

```
        id                              winner                                              
482393  513d7a69fdc9f03587006808        left
653153  513d5fc2fdc9f03587003c2d        right
1006476 5140c948fdc9f049260024b4        right
482393  513ceda3fdc9f035870023db        left
653153  5185d41afdc9f03fd500137c        right
1006476 50f5e76afdc9f065f0007152        right
```

I've tried `pd.melt(test_cat, id_vars=['left_id', 'right_id'], value_vars=['winner'])` but can't reproduce my expected output. How do I go about doing this?

Example data:

```
pd.DataFrame({'left_id': {482393: '513d7a69fdc9f03587006808',
  653153: '513d5fc2fdc9f03587003c2d',
  1006476: '5140c948fdc9f049260024b4'},
  'right_id': {482393: '513ceda3fdc9f035870023db',
  653153: '5185d41afdc9f03fd500137c',
  1006476: '50f5e76afdc9f065f0007152'},
  'winner': {482393: 'left', 653153: 'right', 1006476: 'right'}}
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap parameters in [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
df = pd.melt(test_cat, 
             value_vars=['left_id', 'right_id'], 
             id_vars=['winner'], 
             value_name='id')
print (df)
  winner  variable                        id
0   left   left_id  513d7a69fdc9f03587006808
1  right   left_id  513d5fc2fdc9f03587003c2d
2  right   left_id  5140c948fdc9f049260024b4
3   left  right_id  513ceda3fdc9f035870023db
4  right  right_id  5185d41afdc9f03fd500137c
5  right  right_id  50f5e76afdc9f065f0007152
```

If need also index values:

```
df = (pd.melt(test_cat.reset_index(), 
             value_vars=['left_id', 'right_id'], 
             id_vars=['winner', 'index'])
        .set_index('index')
        .rename_axis(None))

print (df)

        winner  variable                     value
482393    left   left_id  513d7a69fdc9f03587006808
653153   right   left_id  513d5fc2fdc9f03587003c2d
1006476  right   left_id  5140c948fdc9f049260024b4
482393    left  right_id  513ceda3fdc9f035870023db
653153   right  right_id  5185d41afdc9f03fd500137c
1006476  right  right_id  50f5e76afdc9f065f0007152
```

Or use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = test_cat.set_index('winner', append=True).stack().reset_index([1,2], name='id')
print (df)
        winner   level_2                        id
482393    left   left_id  513d7a69fdc9f03587006808
482393    left  right_id  513ceda3fdc9f035870023db
653153   right   left_id  513d5fc2fdc9f03587003c2d
653153   right  right_id  5185d41afdc9f03fd500137c
1006476  right   left_id  5140c948fdc9f049260024b4
1006476  right  right_id  50f5e76afdc9f065f0007152
```

Comment: Excellent..!! You might also include the `value_name` feild in melt just to name the variable as `id` . :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use NumPy for a verbose, but adaptable, approach:

```
import numpy as np

res = pd.DataFrame({'id': df[['left_id', 'right_id']].values.ravel(),
                    'winner': np.repeat(df['winner'], 2)},
                   index=np.repeat(df.index, 2))

print(res)

                               id winner
482393   513d7a69fdc9f03587006808   left
482393   513ceda3fdc9f035870023db   left
653153   513d5fc2fdc9f03587003c2d  right
653153   5185d41afdc9f03fd500137c  right
1006476  5140c948fdc9f049260024b4  right
1006476  50f5e76afdc9f065f0007152  right
```

Performance should be comparable to `pd.melt`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not manually (at least a solution haha.):

```
df2=pd.DataFrame()
df2['id']=df['left_id'].tolist()+df['right_id'].tolist()
df2['winner']=df['winner'].tolist()*2
df2.index=df.index.tolist()*2
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
                               id winner
482393   513d7a69fdc9f03587006808   left
653153   513d5fc2fdc9f03587003c2d  right
1006476  5140c948fdc9f049260024b4  right
482393   513ceda3fdc9f035870023db   left
653153   5185d41afdc9f03fd500137c  right
1006476  50f5e76afdc9f065f0007152  right
```

Comment: @jpp Oh yeah, that's right, but i don't really want to edit because then it will basically that same as yours

Answer (score 0):

#### Comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [[i, w] for *I, w in df.values for i in I],
    columns=['id', 'winner']
)

                         id winner
0  513d7a69fdc9f03587006808   left
1  513ceda3fdc9f035870023db   left
2  513d5fc2fdc9f03587003c2d  right
3  5185d41afdc9f03fd500137c  right
4  5140c948fdc9f049260024b4  right
5  50f5e76afdc9f065f0007152  right
```